# Unable to call shellscript using concourse pipeline

Tags: concourse

Overview:
I have created the sample springboot application and convered as images and uploaded to docker hub now am trying to deploy sample application in AWS EC2 instance through Concourse pipeline but getting the error like docker not found .

Image pull is happing sucessfull but when am cheked in EC2 instance no images found am not sure where the images getting dowloaded in concourse

ex:

get: my-docker-image

daef329d350: Pull complete
d85151f15b66: Pull complete
52a8c426d30b: Pull complete
8754a66e0050: Pull complete
af90ecb11369: Pull complete
5b546839c9ce: Pull complete
Digest: sha256:10bef16b70fbf98882181dfcab8df85d3d325e363d978b04b4a7ea8af8aa5c8b
Status: Downloaded newer image for XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX@ssha256:10bef16b70fbf98882181dfcab8df85d3d325e363d978b04b4a7ea8af8aa5c8b
docker.io/XXXXXXXXXX@/springboot@sha256:10bef16b70fbf98882181dfcab8df85d3d325e363d978b04b4a7ea8af8aa5c8b

### Successfully pulled
XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX@sha256:10bef16b70fbf98882181dfcab8df85d3d325e363d978b04b4a7ea8af8aa5c8b.
ERROR:

task:use-docker-image
selected worker: 292dbf447e65

- docker pull XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX
  **sh: 1: docker: not found**

**Yaml file:**
resources:

- name: my-docker-image
  type: docker-image
  source:
  repository: XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX
  tag: latest
  aws_access_key_id: ((XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX))
  aws_secret_access_key: ((XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX))
  aws_region: ap-south-1

jobs:

- name: pull-docker-image
  plan:

  - get: my-docker-image
  - task: use-docker-image
    config:
    platform: linux
    image_resource:
    type: docker-image
    source:
    repository: XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX
    tag: latest
    aws_access_key_id: ((XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX))
    aws_secret_access_key: ((XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX))
    aws_region: ap-south-1
    run:
    path: sh
    args:
    - -exc
    - |
    # You can now use the pulled Docker image
    docker run -d -p 8081:8081 XXXXXXX/XXXXXXXXXX:latest

Need solution for this